# How to create a new column in a DataFrame from a calculation that includes the mean of some values of one column

Tags: python, dataframe, calculated-columns

I need to create a column in a DataFrame`df` that it has the calculation of the mean of some values from columns.

I have a DataFrame with the columns:
'E' 'I' 'D'
and I need to create another column named 'S' that is calculated like this:
`'S' = ('E' + 'I' - 'D') / X`
**where X is the mean of the last seven values of 'D'**

I tried:

```
df[S] = []
for i in range(n):
  Stock = (df[E] + df[I] - df[Despachos]) / (sum(...)/7)
  df[S].append(Stock)
print(df)
```

Of course I got an error because I really don't know how to calculate my **X** which corresponds to that summatory I tried to do

Answer (score 0):

assume your dataframe is called `df`:

`df['Des'] = (df['E'] + df['I'] - df['D']) / df['D'].tail(7)`